# TimeTable creation using graph colouring in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph-coloring

I am working on an ASP application which is about creating time table (scheduling of classes) for my final semester project. I have used the logic from a basic console application program of graph colouring and incorporated into my project. Though the logic for a console application works as required, I am unable to do the same for my asp project.

```
try
        {
            int n = 10, i, j, max = 0, col, ct = 0, rt = 0, m, count = 2, g = 0;
            int[][] a = new int[20][];
            int[] c = new int[20];
            int[] arr = new int[20];
            for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
            {
                c[k] = 0;
                arr[k] = 0;
                a[k] = new int[20];
                for (int l = 0; l < 20; l++)
                {
                    a[k][l] = 0;
                }
            }

            string num = null, num1 = "";
            string display = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Subjects WHERE USN IN(SELECT USN FROM tbl_Student WHERE Semester='" + DropDownList1.Text + "')";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdSql = new SqlCommand(display, con);
            SqlDataReader rs;
            rs = cmdSql.ExecuteReader();


            while (rs.Read())
            {
                //count1++;

                for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
                {
                    g = k - 1;
                    num = rs[k].ToString();
                    arr[g] = Convert.ToInt32(num);
                    num1 += arr[g] + " ";
                }
                num1 += "\n";

                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = (k + 1); l < n; l++)
                    {
                        if (arr[k] == 1 && arr[l] == 1)
                        {
                            a[k][l] = 1;
                            //a[l][k] = 1;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            rs.Close();
            TextBox3.Text = num1;
            num1 = "";
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
                {
                    num1 += a[k][l] + " ";
                }
                num1 += "\n";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                c[i] = 0;
                //for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                //scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            }
            c[0] = 1; c[1] = 2;
            for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    if (a[i][j] > 0)
                    {
                        m = 0;
                        for (col = 0; col < n; col++)
                        { if (a[i][col] > 0)rt++; if (a[col][i] > 0)ct++; }
                        m = rt; if (ct > rt) m = ct;
                        if (m < 2) { if (a[0][i] > 0)c[i] = 2; else c[i] = 1; } else { c[i] = count; if (m > max) { max = m; count++; } }
                        rt = 0; ct = 0;
                    } if (c[i] < 1) if (c[i - 1] > 1) c[i] = 1; else c[i] = 2;
            }

            string result = "";
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                result += "Subject[" + (i + 1) + "] = " + c[i] + "\n";
                if (c[i]==1)
                {
                    TextBox4.Text += "Subject 1 = 8:15 to 9:15 \n";
                }
                if (c[i] == 2)
                {
                    TextBox4.Text += "Subject 2 = 9:15 to 10:15 \n";
                }
                if (c[i] == 3)
                {
                    TextBox4.Text += "Subject 3 = 10:45 to 11:45 \n";

                }
                if (c[i] == 4)
                {
                    TextBox4.Text += "Subject 4 = 11:45 to 12:45 \n";
                }
                if (c[i] == 5)
                {
                    TextBox4.Text += "Subject 5 = 1:30 to 2:30 \n";
                }
                if (c[i] == 6)
                {
                    TextBox4.Text += "Subject 6 = 2:30 to 3:30 \n";
                }
                if (c[i] == 7)
                {
                    TextBox4.Text += "Lab 1 = 8-15 to 10:15 \n";
                }
                if (c[i] == 8)
                {
                    TextBox4.Text += "Lab 2 = 10:45 to 12:45 \n";
                }
                if (c[i] == 9)
                {
                    TextBox4.Text += "Lab 3 = 1:30 to 3:30 \n";
                }
                if (c[i] == 10)
                {
                    TextBox4.Text += "Lab 4 = 8-15 to 9:15 \n";
                }
            }
            con.Close();
           TextBox2.Text = result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Label2.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

In the above code, I'm reading the data i.e 0's and 1's of the adjacency matrix from the database onto which the graph colouring algorithm is applied. Once the colouring has been performed, results are printed on a textbox for time being.

The problem I am facing is, the colors are not being assigned and not able to generate the time table.

Comment: Use a RichTextbox instead of a TextBox.  A Textbox doesn't support colors.

Comment: That bunch of if clauses... use a switch, much cleaner and you wouldn't need to check 9 ifs if your case is 10..

Comment: Hello Sir, I am using the textboxes just to display the variable information, at a later point I am going to use Grid View in order to display the subjects. 

Regarding the switch cases, thanks for the suggestion. However, I wont be displaying any colors, I will be displaying only the final result after coloring has been done, so a textbox would be sufficient?